# Autocreate cluster Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, clustered-index

What is the parameter to be set to elastic search does not allow the creation of automated cluster? 
And what happened if a cluster is automatically created?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search creates the cluster based on the nodes . For node discovery we can use Multicast or Uni-cast

In general development environment we use multicast discovery to true , so that is discoverable . In production we need to use unicast and specify the names as mentioned below and disable the multicast to false.

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2:port"]
```

The cluster name is configured

```
#cluster.name: elasticsearch
```

All these setting are in config folder of Elastic search and will be available in **elasticsearch.yml** file.